# Why does this future.wait_until example have thread.detach()? Doesn't detach lead to memory leaks?

Tags: c++, multithreading

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_until has an example where detach is called on the threads. Why is detach() used? Doesn't it lead to a memory leak of the thread? It's seems odd that cppreference would be using bad techniques. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
 
int main()
{
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point two_seconds_passed
        = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(2);
 
    // Make a future that takes 1 second to complete
    std::promise<int> p1;
    std::future<int> f_completes = p1.get_future();
    std::thread([](std::promise<int> p1)
                { 
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); 
                    p1.set_value_at_thread_exit(9); 
                }, 
                std::move(p1)
    ).detach();
 
    // Make a future that takes 5 seconds to complete
    std::promise<int> p2;
    std::future<int> f_times_out = p2.get_future();
    std::thread([](std::promise<int> p2)
                { 
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5)); 
                    p2.set_value_at_thread_exit(8); 
                }, 
                std::move(p2)
    ).detach();
 
    std::cout << "Waiting for 2 seconds..." << std::endl;
 
    if(std::future_status::ready == f_completes.wait_until(two_seconds_passed))
        { std::cout << "f_completes: " << f_completes.get() << "\n"; }
    else
        { std::cout << "f_completes did not complete!\n"; }
 
    if(std::future_status::ready == f_times_out.wait_until(two_seconds_passed))
        { std::cout << "f_times_out: " << f_times_out.get() << "\n"; }
    else
        { std::cout << "f_times_out did not complete!\n"; }
 
    std::cout << "Done!\n";
}
```

Comment: Indeed thread detach should (IMO) never be used. In this case the code still synchronizes due to the future/promise. What I think they were trying to do is show you that you can avoid races at shutdown even with a detached thread, but yes I agree it is confusing

Comment: The future destructors block until they get ready shared states and they are synchronized with the thread completions.

Comment: You should only detach a thread if you are manually managing its lifetime, Likely this example is just using detach for convenience as it doesn't really have a negative effect in such a small example that is teaching somthing else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`detach` doesn't lead to memory leaks, the thread is still destroyed when it ends.

What it does do is detach the thread's lifetime from the scope it was declared in, this leads to issues if the variables the thread is using are in the same scope. Those variables will be destroyed before the thread finishes leading to undefined behaviour.

Used correctly there's nothing wrong with `detach` however it's generally easier to write a correct program without `detach` than with it.

In this example the threads don't access any external variables so `detach` is safe to use. I imagine it's used here to avoid having to `join` the threads which would distract from what they are demonstrating which is the use of promises.

Comment: Using `std::jthread` with `join` in destructor, avoids a lot troubles.